# iphone NSDate - First Week Of Year Wrong?

Tags: ios, iphone, calendar

I have the following Code:

```
NSDate *myDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:nowComponents];
Monday = myDate;

NSLog(@"1 --> %ld  %ld  %ld", [nowComponents weekday], [nowComponents weekOfYear], [nowComponents year]);
NSLog(@"2 --> %@",myDate);
NSLog(@"3 --> %@", Monday);
```

Before that i set the WeekOfYear of nowComponents to 1 and the Year to 2017.

But i get the following Output:

```
1 --> 2  1  2017
2 --> 2018-01-01 17:59:05 +0000
3 --> 2018-01-01 17:59:05 +0000
```

To Clarify: I want the Week starting with January 2 in 2017.

But if I set WeekOfYear to 1, I get the Output posted above (obviously wrong), and if I set WeekOfYear to 2 I suddenly get the Week starting with January 9 (Wrong too).

So basically: What Value should I set to WeekOfYear to get the Week of January 2 in 2017 ?

What is wrong with my Code ?

Sorry for bad english and thanks for help.